# Ideas for Kids GIS Workshop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I'm working on getting an 8 hour workshop made for Middle and High Schoolers for GIS. I know it can be hard to grab their attention so I was wondering if you guys had any ideas about what we can do to keep them interested. We should be able to have access to ArcMap as well as ArcGIS online. If you guys have any ideas let me know.

Comment: http://www.gisday.com/resources.html

Comment: Any GIS topics related to app development for their smartphones.

Comment: I'm worried that this question is along the lines of a ["Don't Ask" Help example](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) i.e. `“I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”`.  In your case it is more like “I would like to participate in a discussion about ideas for a Kids GIS Workshop”  Raising it in the currently under-used [GIS Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) may be a more suitable place to seek ideas like this.

Comment: You could tell them not to go looking for the person skinny dipping... but make *very* sure first there isn't one! One place I have worked was struggling to get interest in the GIS department, when new aerial photography arrived a rumor was circulated about someone being 'caught in the act' and the number of transactions quadrupled instantly - not that there's anything to see on 12.5cm pixel. The upshot of this is that more users got experience in what the GIS could do and after the ice was broken continued to use it.

Comment: There is [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/help-on-creating-a-presentation-for-highschool-students/5298#5298) similar question already ...

Comment: ... and [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3574/gis-day-function-ideas) ... I think they would be best all made duplicates and the earliest one turned into a [Canonical Q&A as part of our Community Wiki](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/do-we-need-a-list-of-canonical-questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'coolest' thing you could talk about would probably be [**Ingress**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingress_%28game%29), the augmented-reality MMORPG that takes place in the real world, using little more than your smartphone's GPS.

From talking about Ingress, you could probably make conjectures about the next generation of video games: ones that use GIS to 'overlay' games on the real world. That will get the attention of the students.

---

Aside from that: I think kids might easily get bored by the process of GIS manipulation, or by watching someone do stuff in ArcGis or ArcMap. I think the best way to get them interested in GIS is to just show them **end products**: cool maps that display interesting data in engaging ways. While talking about these maps, you can also talk about the way that these maps are constructed -- maybe that will provide a good motivation to introduce actual GIS tools.

Here are some examples of maps that you can freely find on the internet. I'm sure there are lots more.

- Climate change maps (what will the world look like if sea levels rise by x?)
- Inequality maps: the website http://www.radicalcartography.net/ has got **tons** of really interesting maps that highlight social issues. You've probably already seen the ["racial dots"](http://www.radicalcartography.net/index.html?chicagodots) maps that show racial segregation along street lines in major urban centers. Warning: this might be received controversially depending on the students you addressing.
- Map projections: you can talk about different map projections and their uses. One interesting example is that during the cold war, the Mercator Projection became a favorite in the US, because it exaggerated the size of the Soviet Union (as Mercator distorts heavily  in longitude as it approaches the poles) so as to make it seem more of a threat. Maps can be important political tools.
- Historical Maps: for example, [this page](http://www.vox.com/2014/8/19/5942585/40-maps-that-explain-the-roman-empire). Maps are great tools to track societies over time.
- Human impact: [here's a map of the world at night](http://cdn1.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/663570/dnb_land_ocean_ice.2012.3600x1800.0.jpg). I think kids would like this sort of light map.

Other maps that come to mind are oceanographic and topographical maps. The most interesting thing about maps is usually watching them change over time. Climate change forecasts can be interesting to this end.

You could talk about modern satellite mapping and the production of Google Maps and Street View. You could talk about the satellite projects involved in the current and next generations of GIS. Space is usually interesting.

For some more ideas, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system#See_also).

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of [Ballon & Kite mapping](http://publiclab.org/wiki/balloon-mapping) and it is a great way to keep your students engaged for the whole day.